# Flaky unit test involving a timeout

Tags: go, flakyness

I'm trying to debug what appears to be a flaky unit test which is meant to test a fix for adding a timeout. Consider the following simplified handler code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type Service struct {
    client        *http.Client
    repo          Repository
    enableTimeout bool
}

type Repository interface {
    StoreItem(ctx context.Context, id string, b []byte) error
    MarkItemFailed(ctx context.Context, id string) error
}

func (svc *Service) FetchItemFromURL(ctx context.Context, id, url string) error {
    b, err := svc.fetchData(ctx, url)
    if err != nil {
        if repoErr := svc.repo.MarkItemFailed(ctx, id); repoErr != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("mark item failed: %v, original error: %v", repoErr, err)
        }
        return err
    }
    return svc.repo.StoreItem(ctx, id, b)
}

var timeout = 500 * time.Millisecond

func (svc *Service) fetchData(ctx context.Context, url string) ([]byte, error) {
    var cancel context.CancelFunc
    if svc.enableTimeout {
        ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, timeout)
        defer cancel()
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    resp, err := svc.client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("do HTTP request: %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    b, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("read response body: %v", err)
    }

    return b, nil
}
```

Here, it is the code within the `if svc.enableTimeout` block that I'm trying test with the following table-driven test:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

type MockRepository struct{}

var _ Repository = &MockRepository{} // Ensure that *MockRepository satisfies the Repository interface.

func (repo *MockRepository) StoreItem(context.Context, string, []byte) error {
    return nil
}

func (repo *MockRepository) MarkItemFailed(ctx context.Context, _ string) error {
    return ctx.Err() // Return an error if Done is closed.
}

func TestFetchItemFromURL(t *testing.T) {
    var testCases = []struct {
        name            string
        enableTimeout   bool
        errStringFormat string
    }{
        {
            name:            "no timeout for fetching data from URLs",
            errStringFormat: `mark item failed: context deadline exceeded, original error: do HTTP request: Get %q: context deadline exceeded`,
        },
        {
            name:            "with timeout",
            enableTimeout:   true,
            errStringFormat: `do HTTP request: Get %q: context deadline exceeded`,
        },
    }

    for _, tc := range testCases {
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            ts := httptest.NewTLSServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
                time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
                w.Write([]byte("data")) //nolint:errcheck
            }))
            defer ts.Close()

            svc := &Service{
                client:        ts.Client(),
                repo:          &MockRepository{},
                enableTimeout: tc.enableTimeout,
            }

            ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
            defer cancel()

            err := svc.FetchItemFromURL(ctx, "42", ts.URL)
            if err == nil {
                t.Error("Expected an error, got nil.")
            }
            if err.Error() != fmt.Sprintf(tc.errStringFormat, ts.URL) {
                t.Errorf("Got an unexpected error message %q. Expected: %q", err.Error(), fmt.Sprintf(tc.errStringFormat, ts.URL))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

If I run this simplified example locally, it succeeds:

```
> go test ./... -run TestFetchItemFromURL -v -count=1
=== RUN   TestFetchItemFromURL
=== RUN   TestFetchItemFromURL/no_timeout_for_fetching_data_from_URLs
=== RUN   TestFetchItemFromURL/with_timeout
--- PASS: TestFetchItemFromURL (4.01s)
    --- PASS: TestFetchItemFromURL/no_timeout_for_fetching_data_from_URLs (2.00s)
    --- PASS: TestFetchItemFromURL/with_timeout (2.01s)
PASS
ok      github.pie.apple.com/kurt-peek/scratch/flaky-context-canceled   4.149s
```

Note that without the timeout introduced with the `enableTimeout` 'feature flag', the `MarkItemFailed` call fails because the context's deadline has already been exceeded by waiting for a response from the remote URL. With the timeout, however, the fetch from the URL fails but `MarkItemFailed` is still called successfully.

Can anyone tell what might be flaky about this unit test?